# How To Add Node To 3D Box JavaFX

Tags: java

I am working on a 3D Snake game which and I will have the snake moving on a cube but how do I add a rectangle(Snake) to a cube? I have seen nothing online mentioning it.

Here is my code:

```
public class Snake extends Application {

    public static Group root = new Group();
    public static Scene scene;
    public static String axis = "";
    public static double mouseOldX;
    public static double mouseOldY;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Initializes the stage
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Box cube = new Box(300, 300, 300);
        Rectangle snake = new Rectangle(10, 10, Color.BLACK);
        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        Rotate rx = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
        Rotate ry = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        Rotate rz = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        DoubleProperty velocity = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
        double speed = 100;

        camera.setTranslateZ(-1000);
        camera.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera.setFarClip(2000.0);
        camera.setFieldOfView(30);

        material.setDiffuseColor(Color.RED);
        material.setSpecularColor(Color.ORANGE);

        cube.setMaterial(material);
        cube.getTransforms().addAll(rx, ry, rz);
        root.getChildren().add(cube);

        cube.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                    mouseOldX = event.getSceneX();
                    mouseOldY = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        cube.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                    rx.setAngle(rx.getAngle() + (event.getSceneY() - mouseOldY));
                    ry.setAngle(ry.getAngle() + (event.getSceneX() - mouseOldX));
                    mouseOldX = event.getSceneX();
                    mouseOldY = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600, Color.BLACK);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        root.setFocusTraversable(true);
        root.requestFocus();

        stage.setTitle("3D Snake");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "adding" a rectangle (2D Node) to a cube (2D Node)? Using it to colorize one of its faces?

Comment: @JoséPereda The snake would be the rectangle and I want him to move along the faces of the cube in order to collect the food

Comment: Have you tried using a very thin black cube? You could translate it at your convenience.

Comment: @JoséPereda Do you mean moving a black cube along the red one?

Comment: 2D and 3D doesn't mix well, so it's better to go all 3D. Using a thin black box as a "rectangle", will allow placing it at the required position on top of a given face of the big cube.

Comment: @JoséPereda How would I move it to a different face of the big cube though?

Comment: Using translations? It's up to you to define the logic of that movement, but it shouldn't be too hard: keep both boxes in the same `Group` and apply your current rotations and the mouse events to  the group. Then apply local transforms to the black box based on its position referred to the red one.